# Qpixmap image not loading in pyqt4 4.9 python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpixmap

-EDITED

Im using this code to load a picture in a qlabel found in [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/widgets2/). Its working in later version of pyqt4, But not in pyqt4 4.9. Is there a change in using qpixmap in pyqt4 4.9? Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("redrock.png")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()        

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: holy crap, I was just having this same problem and was about to post, thanks. I think my problem is the way that QPixmap handles image paths.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Any errors?

Comment: @Avaris There is no error but the image does not display. Its been fixed by installing pyqt4 4.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same version as you and for this example to work you script must be in the same directory as `redrock.png`

Comment: sorry the version I actually using is pyqt4 4.9. I install the 4.9.1 and it works. I will edit my question again. Thanks for the reply.